# Can I use COPY to add in files when building images on Bluemix?

Tags: build, copy, containers, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I'd like to build my images on Bluemix and not locally.
Can I use COPY to include my own files into the image ?
If so where can I store the files ?

Or maybe if I had the files on github I could pull them from github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

When you run `cf ic build` or `docker build`, the contents of your current directory (your "build context") are sent along with the build request. You can use the `COPY` or `ADD` instructions to add any file or folder within the build context into your container image, just as you can locally.

If you want to use an online source such as Github anyway, you can `ADD` the file from a URL. For more information, see the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

Comment: Got it. Works as you described.  

I have some large files that go into the image and don't want to have to keep uploading them - have a slow upload link.

So for those I'll pull them using `ADD` or maybe a `curl` depending on what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus, you can now use `cf ic cp` to copy files to and from your containers once they are up and running.